# stored procedure to linq in mvc

Tags: c#, sql, model-view-controller

Can you help me to convert my stored procedure into LINQ?

this is my codes in stored procedure

```
 SELECT ooe_general_id, SUM(CAST(CAST(amount AS money) AS float)) AS 
 totalAppro, MAX(date) AS lastDate
 FROM dbo.pmTA_OoeGeneralAppropriation
 WHERE (amount NOT LIKE '-%')
 GROUP BY ooe_general_id
```

I'm getting trouble in converting my stored procedure into LINQ format which I badly needed because i need to use the linq format in MVC to show my datatable

Comment: No we can't because Stackoverflow is not a code conversion tool!

Comment: can i ask a question? is there any converter for stored procedure to linq that i can used ? please help me ... thank you

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @EuniceMalaluan Try to build the query by own as I see that is not much complex. Take reference from https://stackoverflow.com/a/3956125/7124761

Comment: if you're "having trouble" then please show us your attempt at conversion and explain what is wrong with it currently (e.g. any errors you get or unexpected output). BTW you don't technically _need_ to use Linq in MVC...it's perfectly possible to call a stored procedure from an MVC (or any C#) application. If it ain't broke, don't fix it.